# Quotes escapes to correctly pass parameter from HTML input value to a javascript function from a PHP echo

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple PHP echo statement which displays a HTML input box. I want to pass the data in value field when using the setTimeout function.  I can't seem to get the quote escapes correct.  This is my code snippets.

```
//PHP code
echo "<input type='text' id='myId' value='myVal' onkeyup='setTimeout(\"myFunction(this.value)\", 1000);'>";
```

How do I correctly pass [this.value] as a parameter to my myFunction

```
//Javascript code
function myFunction(val){
  alert(val);
}
```

Thanks in advance

-M

Comment: Is `this.value` a php var ?

Comment: If so try `echo "<input type='text' id='myId' value='myVal' onkeyup='setTimeout(\"myFunction(".this.value.")\", 1000);'>";`

Comment: @Lucas If `this.value` was a PHP variable, if would have been `$this.value`.

Comment: indeed :) but in this case I don't know what else it could be

Comment: Hi, this.value is not a PHP variable, it is the value in the HTML stored in the value parameter in this case myVal

Comment: Not a single character of this appears to be dynamic, so why are you outputting it using echo in the first place? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: @misorude this is only an example code, the actual code I'm working with is executed on server side, hence the echo statement.  Please do not question the logic and try to answer the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any quotes there. The Javascript code should look like this:

```
setTimeout(myFunction, 1000, this.value);
```

You pass `myFunction` *as function object* as the first argument; this will be called by `setTimeout`. [`setTimeout` also accepts further arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) which it will pass to the callback, so that's where you pass `this.value`. Since this doesn't involve any quotes, you don't need to worry about them.

Comment: I have seen this, but people mention that it does not work on some IE browsers.  Is there a multi browser compatible option to do the same?

Comment: It's only an issue in IE9 and below. If you really do need to support those in this day and age, you're best off including a polyfill library that backports all sorts of things to old IE versions. In the linked MDN article there's a section specifically for this, including possible workarounds. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Polyfill

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I did use what you provided at first and it works fine but I was looking for alternatives.  I might just stick with this.  Tough luck <= IE9 users.